# Using && after a heredoc in bash

Tags: bash, heredoc

I have a bash script whose commands I chain together using `&&`, as I want the script to stop if individual steps fail.

One of the steps creates a configuration file based on a heredoc:

```
some_command &&
some_command &&
some_command &&
some_command &&
some_command &&
some_command &&
cat > ./my-conf.yml <<-EOF
host: myhost.example.com
... blah blah ...
EOF
... lots more commands ...
```

How can I include this command in the `&&` chain? I tried:

- Placing the `&&` immediately after the EOF. Doesn't work as the EOF has to be on a line by itself.
- Placing the `&&` on a line by itself following the EOF. Doesn't work because bash thinks I'm trying to use `&&` as a command.
- Placing the `&&` before the `>` redirector. Didn't work, as the redirectors are logically part of the command being `&&`-ed.

**CLARIFICATION:**

There are lots of (multiline) commands following the command that generates the config file from the heredoc, so ideally I'm looking for a solution that allows me to place the following commands after the heredoc, which is the natural flow of the script. That is I would prefer not to have to inline 20+ commands on a single line.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

### Chaining commands in a single line

You can put the [control operator](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Definitions) `&&` right after the `EOF` word in your [here document](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Documents) and you can chain more than one command:

```
cat > file <<-EOF && echo -n "hello " && echo world
```

It will wait for your here-document and then will print **hello world**.

#### Example

```
$ cat > file <<-EOF && echo -n "hello " && echo world
> a
> b
> EOF
hello world

$ cat file
a
b
```

---

### Chaining commands after the [heredoc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Documents) delimiter

Now, if you want to place the following commands after the [heredoc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Documents), you can [group](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Grouping) it in curly braces and continue *chaining* commands as follows:

```
echo -n "hello " && { cat > file <<-EOF
a
b
EOF
} && echo world
```

#### Example

```
$ echo -n "hello " && { cat > file <<-EOF
> a
> b
> EOF
> } && echo world
hello world

$ cat file
a
b
```

---

### Using [the set built in](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#The-Set-Builtin)

If you're going to use `set [-+]e` instead of *chained commands* with `&&`, you must notice that surrounding a chunk of code with `set -e` and `set +e` is not a direct alternative and you must take care of the following:

#### Surrounding dependent commands with [`set [-+]e`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#The-Set-Builtin)

```
echo first_command
false # it doesn't stop the execution of the script

# surrounded commands
set -e
echo successful_command_a
false # here stops the execution of the script
echo successful_command_b
set +e

# this command is never reached
echo last_command
```

As you can see, if you need to go on executing commands after the *surrounded* commands, this solution doesn't work.

#### [Grouping Commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Grouping) to the rescue

Instead, you can group the surrounded commands in order to create a subshell as follows:

```
echo first_command
false # it doesn't stop the execution of the script

# surrounded commands executed in a subshell
(
set -e
echo successful_command_a
false # here stops the execution of the group
echo successful_command_b
set +e # actually, this is not needed here
)

# the script is alive here
false # it doesn't stop the execution of the script
echo last_command
```

So, if you need to execute something else after your *chained commands* and you want to use [the `set` builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#The-Set-Builtin), consider the examples above.

Also notice the following about [subshells](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Execution-Environment):

> Command substitution, commands grouped with parentheses, and asynchronous commands are invoked in a subshell environment that is a duplicate of the shell environment, except that traps caught by the shell are reset to the values that the shell inherited from its parent at invocation. Builtin commands that are invoked as part of a pipeline are also executed in a subshell environment. Changes made to the subshell environment cannot affect the shell’s execution environment.

Comment: j.a., thanks for adding the extra information about set +/-e. Really nice answer to this question.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the && operator just to stop at the command that fails and not continue, you might want to surround the chunk of code with set -e and close with set +e. that way you can remove the && and your code will most likely look cleaner.